# Add jar into running environment

Tags: java, import, jar

I've got a question on how to add a jar file with code.

The situation is that I want to allow the customers to choose themselves, which database should be connected. Therefore, I'd like to give them the opportunity to load a custoom `*.jar` into the running software (similar to Add external library in eclipse).

Is there a way how I can manage that? I was trying kind of

```
import System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "\\dbdriver.jar";
```

`java.io.tmpdir\dbdriver.jar` would be the file, where custom jar-library-imports will be stored by my code. But eclipse didn't seem to like it.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you considered using a framework like [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) for this?

Comment: you can use OSGi, or look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811545/on-the-fly-class-loading-with-jars

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to read up on Classloaders and Reflection in order to get an understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of loading jars at runtime.
Please take a look at the following link which is pretty similar to what you're looking for.

[Loading jars at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624907/loading-jars-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are trying to accomplish in a .java file it is not correct, you cannot reference a jar file directly in a java file, you can just import single classes or a group of classes using wildcard '*'.

The best approach, to my knowledge, here would be to install an ORM library and then decide with the client what his choice for "more than one" RDBMS would be.